# get edittext data from other fragment's of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a sliding window effect by using `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`. I have three fragments and only one is visible at a time. All the fragments have some `EditText` views. I wants to access edit text box values of all `Fragment`s (if `Fragment` created) when a menu button click.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a public method to the Fragment subclass that returns the value of the EditText (don't forget to account for when the EditText is not initialized).